# hide full number and display last 4 but unmask the number upon form submission

Tags: php, forms, substring, mask

I need to display a number(the number is retrieved from the db) in the form input field such that only the last 4 digits is visbile, the remaining can be masked as * or X or whatever is applicable.

I know the last 4 can be obtained as follows:

```
$number=substr($number,-4,4);
```

But when i hit the submit button the form validates the input field and checks if the number is a valid number of a specific format.
Therefore when I click on the submit button then I should still be able to unmask the masked numbers or do something similar that would help me validate the whole number.

```
<input type="text" name="no" value="<?php if(!empty($number)){ echo $number;} ?>">
```

So I am not sure how to go about this one?

For eg. If i have a number 786661234.
Its should be dispalyed in the form as XXXXX1234.
When I click and submit the form,
it should be decoded and updated in the database as 786661234

Comment: Store the real number in a `$_SESSION` variable on the server and validate _that_ number instead of the masked one, or check the last four digits match the one sent from your form. There is no way of "unmasking" a string or number.

Comment: I'm really hoping these numbers aren't social security numbers/credit cards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your number in $number variable & get the result:

```
<?php

$number =  "1122334455667788";
$masked =  str_pad(substr($number, -4), strlen($number), '*', STR_PAD_LEFT);
print $masked;

?>
```

Comment: can you put an output example ?

Answer (score 5):

Another option for number masking

```
<?php 
echo str_repeat("x", (strlen($number) - 4)).substr($number,-4,4);
```

?>

Comment: can you put an output example ?